# set Timeout for GPS listening

Tags: android, geolocation, gps, android-location

I'm able to get location update from network provider but when it comes to gps it takes a lot of time for the data to be picked. I want to keep a particular time for which only the GPS listener will work and then move on to network provider after sometime. How to fix this issue ?

This is my code..

```
public void gpslocation()
    {
        final LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this
        .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location)

    {
        updateLocationForGeo(location);
        //update(location);
        // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
        makeUseOfNewLocation(location);

    }

    private void makeUseOfNewLocation(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
            Bundle extras) {
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        System.out.println(provider+ "enabled  provider");

    }   


    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println(provider+ "disabled provider");
        networklocation();



    }

        };


    String locationProvider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(locationProvider,  10 * 1000, (float) 10.0,locationListener);


            }
    public void networklocation()
    {
        final LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this
        .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location)

    {
        updateLocationForGeo(location);
        //update(location);
        // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
        makeUseOfNewLocation(location);

    }

    private void makeUseOfNewLocation(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
            Bundle extras) {
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        System.out.println(provider+ "enabled  provider");

    }   


    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println(provider+ "disabled provider");
        isGpsProvidersDisabled=true;




    }

        };



    String timeProvider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(timeProvider,  1 * 1000, (float) 10.0, locationListener);

            }
public void updateLocationForGeo(Location location){

    System.out.println("location updated");
    double dev_lat = location.getLatitude();
    double dev_lang = location.getLongitude();
    boolean out_of_range=false;

    for(int i=0; i<arrayLength; i++){

        double lattDiff = Math.toRadians(latarr[i]-dev_lat);

         double longDiff =  Math.toRadians(lonarr[i]-dev_lang);

         double distance=(Math.sin(lattDiff/2)*Math.sin(lattDiff/2))+(Math.sin(longDiff/2)*Math.sin(longDiff/2)*Math.cos( Math.toRadians(latarr[i]))*Math.cos( Math.toRadians(dev_lat)));

         System.out.println(distance+"  distance" );
         double c= (2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(distance), Math.sqrt(1-distance)));



             double radius=radarr[i]* 1.60934;



             double d = 6371 * c;


         if(d>radius)
            {

        out_of_range=true;  
            continue;

            }
        else{
            System.out.println("enjoy");
            out_of_range=false;
            break;
            }

    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
        mlocListener);

public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
private Address mAddresses;
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
    loc.getLatitude();
    loc.getLongitude();

    Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(),
            Locale.getDefault());
    try {
        mAddresses = gcd.getFromLocation(loc.getLatitude(),
                loc.getLongitude(), 1);

    } catch (IOException e) {

    }

    String cityName = (mAddresses != null) ? mAddresses.get(0)
            .getLocality() : TimeZone.getDefault().getID();
    String countryName = (mAddresses != null) ? mAddresses.get(0)
            .getCountryName() : Locale.getDefault().getDisplayCountry()
            .toString();


    mCurrentSpeed.setText("Longitude"+loc.getLongitude()+" Latitude"+loc.getLatitude());
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gps Disabled",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gps Enabled",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}
}
```

Comment: Actually io am able to read when network provider is available but when only gps is on nothing happen Any help how to check if gps is working or not will be more helful

Comment: If Gps signal strength is good, you can receive updates for every seconds and whenever on locations changes. Your climate condition may be the first cause, next your device GPS capability may be very low. These are the two cause you cannot get GPS signal

Comment: Yes thats right but i wanna know if i can keep a timer for say 2 minutes and if gps is not located within that time move to the network provider.If that is possible where shud i place the timer ie in which function(isprovider enabled,onlocatin changed,onstatuschanged,etc)?

Comment: oh ok can u please suggest me some idea?

Comment: See How to implement Timer class in android